# HtmlAgilityPack - Getting div content

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

So I am trying to get a list of users online on a forum. Here is what the html looks like:

```
<!-- logged-in users -->
            <div id="wgo_onlineusers" class="wgo_subblock section">
                <h3 class="blocksubhead"><img src="images/metro/red/misc/users_online.png" alt="Currently Active Users" />Currently Active Users</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>There are currently <a href="online.php">3 users online</a>. <span class="shade">3 members and 0 guests</span></p>
                    <p>Most users ever online was 23, 01-06-2013 at <span class="time">12:09 PM</span>.</p>

                    <ol class="commalist" id="wgo_onlineusers_list">

                            <li><a class="username" href="http://website.com/member.php?u=13"><span class="vip_username">Duncanrp</span></a>, </li>

                            <li><a class="username" href="http://website.com/member.php?u=17"><span class="regular_username">Jessica</span></a></li>

                    </ol>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end logged-in users -->
```

Is it possible to get each individual user that is online using the HtmlAgilityPack? The users are formatted using the `<li>` tags.

Code I have attempted:

```
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

            htmlDocument.LoadHtml("http://www.vizor.us/forum.php");

            List<string> onlineUsers = new List<string>();

            foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode selectNode in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li/a[@class='username']"))
            {
                onlineUsers.Add(selectNode.InnerText);
            }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();

 htmlDocument.LoadHtml("http://vizor.us/forum.php");

 List<string> onlineUsers = new List<string>();

foreach (HtmlNode selectNode in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li/a[@class='username']")) {
    onlineUsers.Add(selectNode.InnerText);
            }
        }
```

where  is the string value of the website url that you are parsing.

For explanation of code please review documentation at http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: I tried that method but I get the error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' at the foreach loop.

Comment: Works for given the html snippet provided. I did have to wrap the html in <html><body> elements to make it valid. The code should give you a good starting point to workout the rest.

Comment: I am using the website url 'http://vizor.us/forum.php' and it gives me an error. Updated post.

Comment: You'll need to use HtmlAgility to log in as well then.